# Matlab - intersection of sinusoidal signals

Tags: matlab

I need to find the intersection points of lets say two sinusoids with different frequencies. I tried to make use of Fast and Robust Curve Intersections which yields me an error in memory.

```
Error using repmat
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.
```

e.g.

```
s1 = sin(2*pi*t)
s2 = sin(2*pi*220*t)
[xo,yo] =  intersections(t,s1,t,s2,1)
```

Comment: There is no `repmat` in your code. What is the size of `t` ?

Comment: It seems that there exist in the intersections function i've mentioned i'm trying to use. Vector t is of minor importance at this point, cause all i wanna do is to get intersection points of any two sinusoidal signals.

Comment: Why not just solve the equation explicitly?

Comment: @sayidjetzenden No, the vector `t` seems to be too long to be handled by Matlab, so this is probably what causes your error. This is not what I call a minor point.

Comment: @Ratbert Apparently you are right. I changed the vector and worked just fine. Didnt expect it to cause the trouble, anyway thanks for helping. *edit how do i vote up your answer? still new here

Comment: @sayidjetzenden Glad it helped. Good luck for the rest of your project.